# Widget not redrawing despite Setstate & UniqueKey

Tags: flutter

I have this code for selecting options in a product page.
The index is updating well, but **the color of the selected option refuses to change** (as well as the name of the selected option on the right -- see the image below), and i can't figure why..

I have tried to use Setstate(), and to use unique keys for the related parent widgets

Here the image:
[image]

```
    import 'package:animate_do/animate_do.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:prem_market/models/product.dart';
    import 'package:prem_market/models/product_variation.dart';
    
    class DisplayAttributes extends StatefulWidget {
      const DisplayAttributes({
        Key key,
        this.data,
        Function onChanged,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      final Product data;
    
      @override
      _DisplayAttributesState createState() => _DisplayAttributesState();
    }
    
    class _DisplayAttributesState extends State<DisplayAttributes> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        int activeOption = 0;
    
        return Column(
          children: [
            ...List.generate(
              this.widget.data.attributes.length,
              (index) => !this.widget.data.attributes[index].variation
                  ? SizedBox()
                  : Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                FadeInDown(
                                  delay: Duration(milliseconds: 450),
                                  child: Text(
                                    this.widget.data.attributes[index].name,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                FadeInDown(
                                  delay: Duration(milliseconds: 450),
                                  child: Text(
                                    activeOption == 100
                                        ? '-'
                                        : this
                                            .widget
                                            .data
                                            .attributes[index]
                                            .options[activeOption],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      //color: black.withOpacity(0.7)
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                        FadeInDown(
                          delay: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 25),
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              child: Row(
                                children: this
                                    .widget
                                    .data
                                    .attributes[index]
                                    .options
                                    .asMap()
                                    .map<int, GestureDetector>(
                                        (i, String childData) {
                                      return MapEntry(
                                          i,
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            key: UniqueKey(),
                                            onTap: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                if (activeOption == i) {
                                                  //selected = false;
                                                  activeOption = 100;
                                                } else {
                                                  activeOption = i;
    
                                                  //selected = true;
                                                }
                                              });
                                              FocusScope.of(context)
                                                  .requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                                            },
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  right: 15,
                                                  bottom: 5,
                                                  left: 5,
                                                  top: 5),
                                              child: Container(
                                                key: UniqueKey(),
                                                //width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    horizontal: 10),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: activeOption == i
                                                        ? Theme.of(context)
                                                            .textTheme
                                                            .headline6
                                                            .color
                                                        : Colors.grey[200],
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                                    boxShadow: [
                                                      BoxShadow(
                                                          spreadRadius: 0.5,
                                                          blurRadius: 1,
                                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                                              .shadowColor
                                                              .withOpacity(0.1))
                                                    ]),
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    childData,
                                                    key: UniqueKey(),
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 16,
                                                        color: activeOption == i
                                                            ? Theme.of(context)
                                                                .backgroundColor
                                                            : Theme.of(context)
                                                                .shadowColor),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ));
                                    })
                                    .values
                                    .toList(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting activeOption to 0 in build function make it a global variable.  Everytime you call setState() build method is called which again resets it to 0

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int activeOption = 0;
```

to

```
int activeOption = 0;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought only the variables changed in setstate would be afftected

Comment: setState will call build; and in build you are setting it to 0. The varable is not protected from changes in build. By doing as suggested above - you change the varable in setState - as you expect - but build won't touch it again.